# How can I add a margin to a table cell in Pages?

Tags: pages

How do I change Cell margins and padding? I'm not seeing any options for these anywhere.

Is that possible with Pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the format pane, go to text, layout and adjust text inset.